# Python TCP Socket Service %100 CPU usage

Tags: python, sockets

Hi i am working on TCP Socket listening port with python and insert data into postgresql. OS is Ubunutu Server 16.04.3 LTS. When all client connect first, CPU is not loaded high. And When client disconnect from socket i see socket still connectted and client connected again different socket.Insert is working good.I will listen 2000 client . 
1-How can socket stop when client disconnect ?
2-Why is cpu loaded 100 ?

PY:

```
import socket
import threading
import psycopg2
import string
import datetime
import resource

resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (65536, 65536))
bind_ip = '0.0.0.0'
bind_port = 1339

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
server.listen(5000)  # max backlog of connections

connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "USER",password = "PASS",host = "127.0.0.1",port = "5432",database = "DB")
cursor = connection.cursor()

print 'Listening on {}:{}'.format(bind_ip, bind_port)


def handle_client_connection(client_socket,address):
    while 1:
        request = client_socket.recv(1024)
        request_arr = string.split(request, ",")
        # print 'Received {}'.format(request)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if request_arr[0] == '*HQ':
            try:
                nowdate=now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                nowtime=now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                record_datetime=now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                postgres_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO public.listener (id) VALUES (%s)"""
                record_to_insert = (request_arr[1])
                cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)
                connection.commit()
            except Exception:
                pass
while True:
    client_sock, address = server.accept()
    print 'Accepted connection from {}:{}'.format(address[0], address[1])
    client_handler = threading.Thread(
        target=handle_client_connection,
        args=(client_sock,address[0],)  
    )
    client_handler.start()
```

Comment: A closed socket will return empty from recv() immediately.  Infinite loop.  You have a while 1 loop with no exit condition.

Comment: if I remove it , that will be ok ?

Comment: Remove what? You have to *add* code to detect the end of stream.

Comment: I remove    " while 1:" . but 1 device every device seems connected with multiple socket. First socket not closed for every device

Comment: How can i detect the end of stream ?